# Xcode C++ standalone files aren't compiled

Tags: c++, xcode

Just started using c++ and I've built a little test program. All that happens is that a blue square follows your mouse around in a window. The problem is, that the image used doesn't seem to be IN the actual build file. If I delete the image from the images folder *after* the file is built, or send the build file to another person, the square doesn't show up.

I've searched around for answers but didn't find anything like this.

EDIT: I'm using SFML and just chose "SFML App" as a template.

EDIT AGAIN: Maybe it's because the image path is /Users/*****/Desktop/ObjectiveCTests/Test/player.png. I'm not sure how to link it any other way. I've tried a lot of different paths.

Comment: What kind of product are you building with Xcode?  I mean, is it an application bundle "Something.app" or is it just a command line program?  What APIs are you using to get the image from the disk and to draw the image?

Comment: Why would you think the image will be embedded in an single executable?

Comment: @Shane Because i'm used to developing in AS3 and swf's include all of the files used. Figured the file paths would be updated to their location in the .app file

Comment: If the project doesn't matter to you that much, you can upload it, and we can check the settings for you.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/424013/Test-zip.html is the file for it

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked which build phase Xcode thinks your image file is part of?

You can find this out by clicking on your project, and then selecting the "Build Phases" tab, and then selecting your target. You should see a list of different build phases, each of which has several files in it.  You want to make sure your image is part of the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase, not something else like "Compile Sources".

Take this with a grain of salt--I'm new to Xcode myself, but just had almost the exact same problem with my own project (except in my case it was a glsl fragment shader, not an image file, that wasn't getting bundled correctly.)

Comment: Yeah, it's part of the Copy Bundle Resources phase, and if I open the app, and go into /Contents/Resources I can find the image.

Comment: Maybe an absolute vs. relative path issue then?  If you select the image, and look in the file inspector in the right-side panel, under Location, does it say "Relative to Group"?

Comment: Yes it does. I've heard that the filepath is specific to the file in which it it referenced, and i've also heard that it should be specific to the xcodeproj file. Neither path seemed to work however without using the entire /User/****/Desktop/.../... file path